# Django create custom group perms in admin view

Tags: django, permissions, admin

i'm trying to make a sort  of employee management site for stores inside a franchise so all managers can access the sight but i want them to only be able to see the employees for their store.
i just cant seem to find how to add custom permissions to the groups to make it they can only see people and things from x store rather from all of them. 
is this something that is possible to pull off?

admin

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'slug', 'store', 'position',
                    'joined', 'dob', 'under18', 'student',]
    list_filter = ['store', 'joined', 'under18', 'position']
    list_editable = [ 'store', 'position']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('firstname',)}
    search_fields = ('firstname', 'lastname',)
```

models

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='employees', on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_index=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=25, db_index=True)
    store = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_index=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True, db_index=True)

    joined = models.DateField()
    dob = models.DateField()
    under18 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    student = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

this is what i have and i want to be able to hide `store` from certain groups

Comment: post your models also

Comment: added models, thank you!

Comment: in which model you have user object?

Comment: i don't think i have a user object? sorry new to this part of django, this is all in the admin view if that helps at all

Comment: if there is no user, how you differentiate the people? should have user object, authentication etc

Comment: the users who can login and view it i have just used the default django admin users and for the employees i just created a model as they do not need to login

Comment: in order to link your employee table or any other, you have to add the user to it, you can use the default user class for that

Comment: okay thanks any suggestions on doing that?

Comment: read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/, make user as a foreign key to your class where you need some way of user filter

Comment: beautiful thank you so much!